# Deallocating space occupied by stl

Tags: c++, stl

The free() function of stdlib doesn't work on stl variables.
Is there a common way to deallocate the space held up by an stl (like vectors, maps, sets etc.)?

Comment: You don't have to (in most cases)

Comment: Are you looking for something like the `delete` operator (in case your STL containers are allocated on the heap)?

Comment: @POW so c++ has automatic garbage collection?

Comment: The common way is to let them die at the end of the scope they are declared in. There is no garbage collection as such, because there is no garbage (you can create garbage if you try hard enough though).

Comment: @ishan3243, nope, but most of the time STL containers are allocated on automatic storage (the stack) and are freed at the end of their enclosing scope.

Comment: Normally, you don't need to. They will clean up after themselves.

Comment: They are allocated wherever you allocate them, just like anything else. The data they hold can be allocated on "the heap", but you don't have to de-allocate it.

Comment: `free` doesn't work on `int` variables, `struct` variables, `enum` variables, or array variables either.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Actually, `free(0)` "works" perfectly. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `0` is not a variable.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: You took it too *literal*ly ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STL objects automatically take care of their own deallocations. When a STL object goes out of scope its destructor is run which does necessary deallocations. As Frédéric Hamidi pointed in comment, in case of allocation on heap you should deallocate the object yourself. It is advisable in C++ to use new/delete rather than C's malloc/free combination.

Comment: Unless, of course, it was allocated on the heap through the `new` operator.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: Free store*

Comment: @Light, free store is the right term, yes, I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 1):

`free` is a C function and does not invoke destructors; as such, it is almost always wrong in C++. `delete` is the equivalent in C++.

Still, what you should do here rather depends on what you mean by "STL variables". If you mean C++ Standard Library objects, then you de-allocate them the same way you de-allocate *any* object in C++:

1. If you did not manually memory-manage the object, **do nothing**;

   ```
   int main()
   {
       std::vector<int> v{0,1,2};
   }
   ```
2. If you manually memory-manage the object by creating it with `new`, you could use `delete`;

   ```
   int main()
   {
       std::vector<int>* ptr = new std::vector<int>();
       ptr->push_back(0);
       ptr->push_back(1);
       ptr->push_back(2);
       delete(ptr);
   } // (PLEASE don't do this)
   ```
3. If you manually memory-manage the object by creating it with `new[]` in an array, use `delete[]`.

   ```
   int main()
   {
       std::vector<int>* ptr = new std::vector<int>[1];
       ptr[0].push_back(0);
       ptr[0].push_back(1);
       ptr[0].push_back(2);
       delete[](ptr);
   } // (PLEASE don't do this either)
   ```

However, in cases 2 and 3 you should actually use a smart pointer instead, such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`; manual memory management is *bad*!

You should not attempt to manually memory-manage any elements within a C++ Standard Library container, as the container *owns* these and will already free their memory as needed:

```
int main()
{
   std::vector<int> v{0,1,2};
   delete &v[0];
} // (So, so wrong)
```

Comment: I'm confused about your last sentence. If you do a new, you do a delete. Why the "don't do this" comments? I'm sure there are plenty of situations when you need to create a pointer on a STL data structure...

Comment: Probably to indicate that manual management should be avoided.

Comment: @Kaidjin: If you want to do that, then use a smart pointer such as `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`. We don't do `new` and `delete` ourselves any more in 2013!

Answer (score 1):

You can roll your own allocators to manage objects inside containers your own way.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4795/C-Standard-Allocator-An-Introduction-and-Implement

Some allocators are ready to use ( have a look at boost::pool )